# Stale file handle error when using SMB3

Tags: networking, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I am using a fritz.box NAS in my local network and want to mount the storage during reboot. I used to successfully mount and use it using `SMB1` but as it is not considered secure anymore I opted to upgrade to SMB3. The router supports this option and it is by default activated.

Here's my `/etc/fstab` line for the mount:

```bsh
//<ip>/FRITZ.NAS/ /home/<me>/nas cifs credentials=/home/<me>/.smbcredentials,vers=3.0,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlmssp 0 0
```

It successfully seems to mount as I can `cd` into the `nas` folder and navigate around. But once I try to access files, e.g. `cat` a text file, I get the `Stale file handle` error. E.g.:

```bsh
cat: file.txt: Stale file handle
```

I also tried using `vers=2.0` but that gives me the same results. I also checked `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and both `client min protocol` and `server min protocol` are correctly set to `SMB2`.

I set `log level = 3` and `logging = syslog` in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`. Upon `sudo mount -a` it seems to simply get stuck. It just prints this.

```bsh
CIFS: Attempting to mount //<ip>/FRITZ.NAS/
```

With `SMB1` I get a successful message.

Not sure what else I should try.

Edit:
When I try to execute `cat file.txt` the logs say:

```bsh
CIFS: VFS: bogus file nlink value 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your errors point to a server / client inode discombobulation. Add another option to your cifs mount statement: `noserverino`

Comment: Thanks that did it!